# Sequence Contains No Matching Elements Entity Seed Error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, seeding

Previously I had an Entity Database working. I deleted it, out of haste, so I went to run my program again (thinking it should recreate and repopulate the DB like it did before). However, this time I got a weird error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

on this line of code in my "SampleData.cs" file (location where seed data comes from):

```
52:             new List<Card>
```

ANY idea what is happening here?

App Start Method:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new 
            GoStopPrimer.Models.SampleData());
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

GoStopEntities.cs

```
public class GoStopEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CardType> CardTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Month> Months { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Special> Specials { get; set; }
}
```

Card.cs Model

```
    public class Card
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public int CardTypeId { get; set; }
    public int MonthId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CardArtUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual CardType CardType { get; set; }
    public virtual Month Month { get; set; }
    public virtual Special Special { get; set; }
}
```

Snippet of SampleData.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace GoStopPrimer.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GoStopEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(GoStopEntities context)
        {
            var cardTypes = new List<CardType>
            {
                new CardType { Name = "kwang" },       
            };

            var months = new List<Month>
            {
                new Month { Name = "January" },           
            };

            var specials = new List<Special>
            {    
                new Special { Name = "None" },    
            };

            new List<Card>
            {
                new Card { Name = "Pine", CardType = cardTypes.Single(c => c.Name == "kwang"), Month = months.Single(m => m.Name == "January"), CardArtUrl = "/Content/Images/Cards/jan1.gif", Special = specials.Single(s => s.Name == "None") },
                new Card { Name = "Willow/Rain", CardType = cardTypes.Single(c => c.Name == "kwang"), Month = months.Single(m => m.Name == "January"), CardArtUrl = "/Content/Images/Cards/dec4.gif", Special = specials.Single(s => s.Name == "None") },
            }.ForEach(c => context.Cards.Add(c));    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code here, which means anyone answering the question needs to trawl through and understand what your problem is. Are you able to narrow the problem down at all?

Comment: I actually thought I shortened the code down a lot @.@ Since I am new to using Entity, I wasn't sure if maybe I was missing something syntactically? If maybe there was something wrong with how I was trying to insert cards into the database via new List<Card>? If it's not seeding at all? Is there a better way I can use my file to seed this data? I'm really stuck, and I don't even know what this error message really means. I was showing all the other code just as references in case someone wanted to know how I was setting things up in my Application_Start method, how my card class looks, etc.

Comment: The problem is most likely in one of the `Single` calls at the end. Check for typos in those names you search for in the `Single` predicates. Do they all match *exactly* with the names you added to the lists?

Comment: Use SingleOrDefault and just debug if this is the correct query

Comment: Slauma you were absolutely right - I had forgotten to add a new "Special" field. Thank you so much!

Comment: if you've solved problem, please edit your question to explain and mark as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I had forgotten to add a new "Special" field".